# How would I add a sound variable to my code?

Tags: unity, javascript, sound, sound-effects

I am writing some code in JavaScript for a ray cast shooting program. I have all the variables I need except for sound, and I'm not too sure on how to add that variable into my code. I would really appreciate any help people can give to solve this problem, and show me how to add a sound variable to my code.

```js
#pragma strict

var Effect : Transform;
var Damage = 100;

function Update () {

 var hit : RaycastHit;
 var ray : Ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Vector3(Screen.width*0.5, Screen.height*0.5, 0)); 
 
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
 {
  if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit, 100))
  {
   hit.transform.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", Damage, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Look [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.html).

Comment: I also recommend switching to C# as soon as possible. It takes all of three regex replacements: `var foo : Bar;` -> `Bar foo;`, `function foo() : Bar` -> `public Bar foo()`, and (for parameters inside functions) `foo : Bar` -> `Bar foo` (which you can catch with the first, if the first just removes the `var`)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an audio source to your GameObject and assign it with an `AudioClip`, then you can play the sound like this when your raycast hits something.

```
#pragma strict

var Effect : Transform;
var Damage = 100;
var AudioSource : AudioSource;

function Start () {
    AudioSource = GetComponent.<AudioSource>();
}

function Update () {
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    var ray : Ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Vector3(Screen.width*0.5, Screen.height*0.5, 0)); 

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit, 100))
        {
            hit.transform.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", Damage, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            AudioSource.Play();
        }
    }
}
```